# How to change Background image on hover of asp:CommandField in a Gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview, onmouseover, commandfield

This is the code for CommandField with, background image.

`<asp:CommandField DeleteImageUrl="~/cms_images/cancel.gif" ShowDeleteButton="true" ButtonType="Image" />`

I would like to show this image `"~/cms_images/cancel-hover.gif"` when a user hovers on the CommandField.
How do I do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Just out of curiousity, why would you want that to happen on the server-side?  Image rollovers are usually handled client-side via JavaScript/JQuery, eliminating the need for posting the page back to the server to simply swap out an image.

Comment: Sorry for complicating. I wanted to mention the mouseout & mouseover images on the server side, not the actual swapping. Edited accordingly.

Comment: I'm still not sure why you're wanting to accomplish this on the server side, as it seems unnecessarily complex.  If a user moves the mouse over the button and it results in a postback to the server, by the time the button is redrawn the mouse may no longer be over it.

Comment: i think you are confused by server side and client side. hover on server side will be a nightmare. wow postbacks everywhere like mine fields :)

Comment: I was thinking setting JS on server side. `e.Row.Attributes["onmouseover"] = "this.style.color='DodgerBlue';this.style.cursor='pointer';";` Not about postbacks for every hover.

Comment: @Rakasi - nice edits; you made the question much more approachable and effective.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can accomplish this with CSS. In the page markup you just need to declare a specific style for the command field - essentially this is the CSS style of the button:

```
<asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="true" ButtonType="Button" ControlStyle-CssClass="cancel" />
```

And in .css file define this style, and define how it changes when user hovers the element:

```
.cancel
{
    background-image: url(cms_images/cancel.gif);
}

.cancel:hover
{
    background-image: url(cms_images/cancel-hover.gif);
}
```

Note that in CSS you should provide a URL relative to the page location. In the code above I assume that the page is situated in the root folder of the web site.

Comment: When I use this code, in the rendered HTML `src` attribute of `<input type="image"` (CommandField) is empty.

Comment: @Andrei: please set the `ButtonType="Button"` and then your code will work. +1